# How to compile files in a subdirectory with a makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Here's what my directory looks like:

```
src/
    dir/
        file2.c
        file2.h
    file1.c
    file1.h
    makefile
```

When I use my makefile, I get:
`gcc: error: file2.o: No such file or directory`

Using from src directory: `gcc -c dir/file2.c dir/file2.h`
I get the correct .o which is created in `src`(that's what I want).
But using the makefile, I get the error above.

The simplest version of my makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -I$(LIBRE_INC) -Iinclude -std=gnu99
LDFLAGS = -lm
EXEC = out
CC = gcc

out :  file1.o file2.o
    ${CC} -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

file1.o: file1.c file1.h

file2.o: dir/file2.c dir/file2.h

%.o : %.c
    ${CC} -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

The make gives:

```
gcc -c file1.c -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -I -Iinclude -std=gnu99 -lm
gcc -o out file1.o file2.o -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -I -Iinclude -std=gnu99 -lm
gcc: error: file2.o: No such file or directory
makefile:7: recipe for target 'out' failed
make: *** [out] Error 1
```

I know that the issue is coming from

```
%.o : %.c
    ${CC} -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

But I don't know how to replace it

Edit:
I added this line under every file where I had a subdir and it worked

```
${CC} -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

I'm still looking for better way if there are !

Comment: regarding these statements: `CFLAGS = -ansi -Wall -pedantic -g -I$(LIBRE_INC) -Iinclude -std=gnu99
LDFLAGS = -lm
EXEC = out
CC = gcc`  this will cause the make facility to re-evaluate each of these macros each time the macro is referenced.   strongly suggest replacing `=` with `:=`

Answer (score 2):

`%.o: %.c` tells make that it can build `file2.o` if `file2.c` exists, and it can build `dir/file2.o` if `dir/file2.c` exists. But you want to build `file2.o` from `dir/file2.c`. Your makefile does not provide any instruction on how to do that.

One solution, which is generally convenient if you never have files with the same name in different directories, is to tell make to search source files in different directories. With the [`VPATH` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html#General-Search) or the [`vpath` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Selective-Search.html#Selective-Search), you can instruct make to look for a source file in `dir` if it can't find it in the top directory. Add

```
VPATH = dir
```

or

```
vpath %.c dir
```

or

```
vpath file2.c dir
```

to your makefile.

Answer (score 2):

Storing all object files in one directory, even when the source files are in different directories, is asking for trouble. What happens when you have `init.c` and `dir/init.c`? The object files `init.o` overwrite each other.

I would replace each `file2.o` with `dir/file2.o` and it should work.

Besides, your pattern rule

```
%.o : %.c
    ${CC} -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

does not use `$@` to reference the target, which it should, according to proper `makefile` engineering:

```
%.o : %.c
    ${CC} -c $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```